# CIDetector not working for QR images

Tags: objective-c, iphone, qr-code, ciimage, cidetector

I am using the following code to fetch an image from the Gallery containing QR code. The problem I am facing is the qr code is detected in some devices and is not detected in other.
    From the looks of it, what I diagnosed was that the devices with iOS 10.7 and lesser are not detecting the QR code whereas from iOS 10.7 greater, the code is working fine.
    How can i get it working under iOS 10.7 and lesser devices. I did not find any help regarding this. If any body has any link or solution regarding this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance[image: ![Unscanable picture]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZKrD.jpg)
    I am also attaching the image that has to be scanned.

**Code Used:**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    BOOL qrcodedetected = NO;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];       
    // QRCode detector
    NSDictionary *detectorOptions = @{ CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh };
    CIDetector *faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:nil options:detectorOptions];
    NSArray *features = [faceDetector featuresInImage:chosenImage.CIImage];
    CIQRCodeFeature *faceFeature;
    for(faceFeature in features)
    {
        qrcodedetected = YES;
        self.decodedstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",faceFeature.messageString];
        break;
    }
}
```